# how to get restart command for server minecraft to work 1.16.3

Tags: minecraft

hello everyone sorry if I'm asking a stupid question but when I restart my Minecraft server it doesn't restart it just acts like I did the stop command I just wanted to be able to restart

Answer (score 0):

On our server we use a plugin called AutoRestart it is very useful since it automatically restarts the server at the time we set it and it has this command called /autore now witch restarts the server on use. If you already have spigot i reccomend you to add it not only you can put the server to restart every now and then but the restrt commands fro this plugin i have tested it and works.

Comment: oh I don't know if that would work for me because on my server I do /restart but it just acts like I did /stop

Answer (score 0):

What you should do is going into your spigot.yml file [I hope you are using Spigot/Paper] and editing the "restart script" line from restart.sh to yourstartupscript.sh/bat [sh for Linux bat for Windows] then restart your server. Doing this should make /restart work.